# Creating string index array from string

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a string which i want to convert into a string indexed array for easy use.

Below is my expectations and outcomes.

Can someone guide me through this?

String: `Dim QueryResponse = "TVShow=Adventure Time" & vbCrLf & "Color=Red"`

Array:

```
Array
(
    ["TVShow"] => "Adventure Time"
    ["Color"] =>  "Red"
)
```

My current code:
`Dim result() As String = QueryResponse.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Current code array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "TVShow=Adventure Time"
    [1] =>  "Color=Red"
)
```

Would love some opinions on this one, thanks!

Comment: Your expected result is more a _Dictionary<string,string>_ than an array

Comment: Perfect! I have implemented that, now just researching some small things and im away :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of an array

```
  Dim dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
  Dim result() As String = QueryResponse.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  Dim res1 As String = result(0)
  Dim res2 As String = result(1)
  'Split res1 and res2 into arrays using '=' as delimeter
  Dim res1s() As String = Split(res1,"=")
  Dim res2s() As String = Split(res2,"=")
  dictionary1.Add(res1(0),res1(1))
  dictionary1.Add(res2(0),res2(1))
```

To access the dictionary entries, use

```
Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
    For Each pair In dictionary1
        You can access the values here using `pair.key` and `pair.value`
        'Eg Label1.Text = pair.key or Console.WriteLine(pair.value)
    Next
```

Comment: Was writing up my own answer which is technically similar so i will accept this, saves me writing the rest up :D Thanks!